# SQL Optimization: CONNECT BY ... START WITH

Tags: sql, oracle, connect-by

I have a query using `CONNECT BY` and `START WITH` statement like below. The query in the IN clause took less than 5 seconds to run and returns 3000 rows. `fact_table` contains 20M of records. How can I optimize this SQL below because this query takes forever to run :(

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONNECT_BY_ROOT a.dst_ID_key AS root_ID_key, a.src_ID_key
  FROM fact_table a
  CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR a.src_ID_key = a.dst_ID_key
   START WITH a.dst_ID_key IN (SELECT b.ID_key
                           FROM TableA b
                           JOIN TableB c
                             ON (c.name = b.name AND c.school = b.school)
                          WHERE b.status = 'Active')
```

Comment: Oracle I presume? Seriously, *why* would you not tell what RDBMS you are using?

Comment: @Erwin, yes it is Oracle, sorry I missed it.

Comment: Can you show us which indexes are defined on the fact_table?

Comment: this is the index define in FACT_TABLE

Comment: IX_FACT_TABLE_01 Unique SRC_ID_KEY, DST_ID_KEY, SRC_START_DTTM 
IX_FACT_TABLE_02 Unique DST_ID_KEY, SRC_ID_KEY, SRC_START_DTTM 
IX_FACT_TABLE_03 Bitmap IS_DIRECT 
IX_R_FT_DT_1 Normal SRC_ID_KEY 
IX_R_FT_DT_2 Normal DST_ID_KEY 
IX_R_FT_DTV Normal MES_ID_KEY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "in" is very slow.
If this data doesn't need real-time update.
I think you can try this:
1、Don't use distinct
2、Use table connection instead of 'in'
 
3、Use materialized view
Hope helps.Wait for a better answer too. : )

Comment: can you guide me how to replace IN with table connection or materialize view?

Comment: I'm sorry.I misguide you. 2、Use table connection instead of 'in' is not workable. You can try this:create index on column name&school in table b&c

Comment: *using "in" is very slow* in this general form is simply wrong.